# Why do some absent users get a weekly reputation of over 50?

Tags: discussion, reputation

One user called Noldorin on the first page of weekly reputation points has a score of 74, even though he hasn't asked/answered a question since July. Maybe people automatically get reputation points in proportion to how much they already have?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The questions and answers a person posts can still get upvoted (thus earning them reputation) even if the person isn't active on the site.

Comment: duh! yeah of course :)

Answer (score 5):

There is no "automatic" reputation, but these sites are meant to provide a repository of good questions and answers which people can search for help; and when people find them often vote for them.